# mplcursors not getting generated when used with Tkinter. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, interactive, mplcursors

Using mplcursors, I'm not able to add cursors to the plot when plot matplotlib is embedded in tkinter gui. It appears that mouse clicks are not registering. However zoom, pan functions work fine. What am I missing?

I use Anaconda Python 3.7.3, matplotlib 3.0.3, and mplcursors library. https://mplcursors.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#

I am able replicate simple example without tkinter and add interactive cursors as needed. I am also able to embed matplotlib plot in tkinter application. However when both are combined - even though plot is shown without errors, interactive cursors are not working.

```py
import tkinter

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np
import mplcursors


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.wm_title("Embedding in Tk")


t = np.arange(0, 3, .01)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
line = ax.plot(t, 2 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * t))

mplcursors.cursor(line)

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root)
toolbar.update()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)


def on_key_press(event):
    print("you pressed {}".format(event.key))
    key_press_handler(event, canvas, toolbar)


canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", on_key_press)


def _quit():
    root.quit()
    root.destroy()  

button = tkinter.Button(master=root, text="Quit", command=_quit)
button.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM)

tkinter.mainloop()
```

I should be able to add and manipulate cursors like in example without tkinter.

Comment: The problem comes from the use of `pyplot`. As you can see from the [embedding in tk example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html), no pyplot should be used when embedding.

Comment: I tried it with figure as well, same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. You should not use pyplot when embedding matplotlib in GUIs. Refer to the [embedding in tk example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html).
2. `mplcursors` needs to work with the figure canvas. So it can only be used once the canvas is defined. So that codeline needs to come *after* defining `FigureCanvasTkAgg`.

Complete code:

```
import tkinter

from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
# Implement the default Matplotlib key bindings.
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

import numpy as np
import mplcursors


root = tkinter.Tk()
root.wm_title("Embedding in Tk")


t = np.arange(0, 3, .01)

fig = Figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line = ax.plot(t, 2 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * t))

canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)

mplcursors.cursor(line)

canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canvas, root)
toolbar.update()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)


def on_key_press(event):
    print("you pressed {}".format(event.key))
    key_press_handler(event, canvas, toolbar)


canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", on_key_press)


def _quit():
    root.quit()
    root.destroy()  

button = tkinter.Button(master=root, text="Quit", command=_quit)
button.pack(side=tkinter.BOTTOM)

tkinter.mainloop()
```

Comment: That was it. After these changes my sample code worked. However, my main code landed in other problem when I used grid layout and toolbar was enabled. Although plot was visible, and toolbar functionality was working,  clicking plot to add cursor made Python stop working. Using pack layout it works. Just throwing it out there if someone lands into similar issue.

Comment: The example worked even with pyplot. It appears real problem was as mentioned in Point 2 above - mplcursors needs to work with the figure canvas. So it can only be used once the canvas is defined. So that codeline needs to come after defining FigureCanvasTkAgg

Comment: Only because something works, it doesn't mean it should be used. If you weren't using pyplot here in the first place, the code would have thrown an error directly leading to the problem of undefined canvas.